# Discrete Markov chain transitive property

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain with state space $S$. I want to prove (or disprove using a counterexample) the following statement:

For three states $s_i, s_j, s_k \in S$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_v = s_j \mid X_u = s_i) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_v = s_j) > 0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_u = s_i) > 0$ ($u \le v \le w$ nonnegative integers).

My approach was to use the definition of conditional probability, but I can't proof the statement this way. Is it possible to use statistical independence or the Markov property? Intuitively, I think the statement is true, because one can multiply probabilities along paths in the state graph and the product of two positive reals is also positive (but this is not a formal proof).

Any ideas?

Comment: Not a formal proof, but the formal proof works along this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of conditional probability,
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_u = s_i)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k, X_u = s_i)}{\mathbb{P}(X_u = s_i)} \geq \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k, X_v=s_j, X_u = s_i)}{\mathbb{P}(X_u = s_i)} $$
We intersect event in numerator with event $\{X_v=s_j\}$ and the probability decreased. Next apply chain rule to the numerator in r.h.s. of (\ref{1}):
$$\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_u = s_i)\geq \dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_u = s_i)\,\mathbb{P}(X_v = s_j\mid X_u=s_i)\,\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_v=s_j, X_u = s_i)}{\mathbb{P}(X_u = s_i)} $$ 
$$=\mathbb{P}(X_v = s_j\mid X_u=s_i)\,\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_v=s_j, X_u = s_i) $$ 
$$=
 \mathbb{P}(X_v = s_j\mid X_u=s_i)\,\mathbb{P}(X_w = s_k \mid X_v=s_j) > 0. 
$$
In the last equality we applied Markov property.

Comment: Why does the probability decrease in (1) when intersecting with ${ X_v = s_j }$ ?

Comment: Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$, $\mathbb P(A\cap B)\leq \mathbb P(A)$ - this is the property of monotonicity of probability.